# Android Tablet to Serial Port Device Connection

Tags: android, android-emulator, serial-port

I have a vending machine that can communicate with an external device using a serial port connection.  I have been able to bridge my computer with the vending machine using a USB → serial port setup.  I would like to do the same with my Android tablet.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using Slick USB

App link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=slickdevlabs.apps.usbtoserialterm&hl=en

Comment: Hi Lloyd are you able to provide further information regarding this solution, as I am attempting a similar project?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest i can imagine is [BluetoothSocket](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html) and a Bluetooth->serial dongle. To drive your USB->serial port setup you need the tablet to have USB host capability (which it might have) but also probably rooting the tablet OS. If you are a DIY type, consider [IOIO](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10748)